# Biggest sum query doesn't work for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to find the maximum sales for a certain period through elasticsearch. However, for some reason my query doesn't find the maximum sales. This is the query I have come up with:

```
GET stock/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "offer.product.id",
        "order": {
          "sum_sales": "desc"
        },
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_sales": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sales"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query gives the following response in my example:

```
"buckets" : [{
  "key" : 241630,
  "doc_count" : 67,
  "sum_sales" : {
    "value" : 1621.0
  }
}]
```

However, the maximum sales is actually 1733 which can be seen in the following example with the query:

```
GET stock/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "offer.product.id": "241630"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_product": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "offer.product.id",
        "order": {
          "sum_sales": "desc"
        },
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_sales": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "sales"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the result:

```
"buckets" : [{
  "key" : 241630,
  "doc_count" : 73,
  "sum_sales" : {
    "value" : 1733.0
  }
}]
```

I do not understand what is wrong with my initial query. Is there something I am missing?

I solved the issue by adding a bigger size, from 1 to a 100. But is there no better way. How can there be a guarantee that I wouldn't need to use a bigger bucket size in the future? (Since a bigger bucket size drastically decreases performance)

Comment: Hi, May I ask you how many shards does your index have? it surely is upper that one. Am I right?

Comment: 5 shards and 1 replica for this index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using a [pivot transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html) for elasticsearch.

I grouped the transform for product and have a field called sum_sales, which is the sum of sales. Doing this makes me able to use normal filters on fields, which give me accurate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As the number of shards is upper than 1, this is a normal behavior for elasticsearch. When the number of shards are upper than 1, elasticsearch performs aggs on each shard separately and get the top `x` number of total results and send them to master node for final calculation. You can see it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in `shard_size` section. This `x` is size*1.5 +10 as default.

It means that when you run your `terms` `aggs` by size of 10, each shards returns 25 number of buckets. It is possible to have bucket in the top 25 of first shard but it is not in the first 25 results of the second shard. Because of that the `aggs` result is not totally accurate. To be more accurate, you can increase `shard_size`. it will have negative influence over your execution time, surely. for this purpose you can add the line to your query:

```
aggs:{
 "sales_per_product": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "offer.product.id",
        "size": 1,
        "shard_size": 30
     }
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you check this? did it work for you?